# Dynamic webpages on BCHS

Tags: webserver, openbsd, sqlite

Ok now that I have generously coated myself in flame-war retardant.

I have an existing [webapp/server](https://github.com/ArchNemSyS/Concise-ILE) written in c++/qt. Having selected OpenBSD as the hosting OS for [security reasons](http://kristaps.bsd.lv/absdcon2016/#slide25).

If I use the [BCHS stacks](https://www.learnbchs.org/index.html) httpd must I use FastCGI to generate dynamic content, as the webapp already understands http I find [FastCGI a Pointless](https://ef.gy/fastcgi-is-pointless) overhead ?

If I replace httpd with my webapp any suggestion how it should be sandboxed ?

Comment: You're going to write your own web server?

Comment: I wish, it is just webapp on top of a QtWebApp a server framework. but the app does server static and dynamic content so it could replace httpd.

Comment: that article you cite is realllly stretching it - sure, implementing fastcgi from the ground up isn't going to be easy, but using the existing libraries is simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running C++ CGI application in Apache is fairly straightforward. And it actually convenient if you entire code base is C++ and you just want a basic web user interface. At work we did a internal portal with this technique. Never did FastCGI since only a handful of people used the service. But I think you have taken your design a step further which few have ventured.

Apache (or probably any httpd) will let you run specific URL as a specific user which can sandbox the process. That would be my recommendation right there. But if you decide you want to use QtWebApp a server framework then the framework needs to have that ability (my guess is it doesn't) -or- inside your WebApp you need [spawn a process as another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048015/linux-c-programming-execute-as-user) and hope it doesn't cause problems in your framework.